# Leer y escribir txt en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo el siguiente fichero prueba.txt:

```
'campo1','campo2','campo3','campo4'
'2222','34563434','547348568765756556','78967756K      '
'2222','34564232','343575876567567584','65876566W      '
'2222','54754456','234223144675987666','43453534A      '
```

Necesito encriptar campo2, campo3 y campo4 con la función DES3 de la librería Crypto.Cipher. Tengo escrito el siguiente código:

```
import pandas as pd
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
infile = mainpath + "/" + "Prueba Encriptacion.txt"
outfile = mainpath + "/" + "Prueba Encriptacion out.txt"
cipher = DES3.new("4QGdtHLBSKmAJaOJY5BW")
df = pd.read_csv(infile, ',')
for row in df.iterrows():
    campo2_out= cipher.encrypt(campo2)
    campo3_out=cipher.encrypt(campo3)
        campo4_out=cipher.encrypt(campo4)
```

Mi problema es que no se como puedo recorrer correctamente las filas del fichero y escribir en el outfile el resultado de la función cipher.encrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre como recorrer las filas, pues algo de la forma `for linea in lineas:` y haciendo uso de las posiciones de los arreglos que devuelva el iterador `reader`, y para escribir, tienes que abrir el archivo en modo escritura, después, cada palabra encriptada, la escribes en el nuevo archivo.

Algo que no sé es el formato de ese archivo de salida ¿También es en csv? Si es ese caso, este código de puede ser de ayuda.

```
import csv
import os
#import pandas as pd

from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

infile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "prueba.txt")
outfile = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "out.txt")

cipher = DES3.new("e5t4esunaNuev4Cn")

with open(infile, 'rb') as csvfile,\
     open(outfile, 'wb') as out:
#       |___________________|
#                 |
#                 |____ Abres cada archivo en modo lectura
#                       y escritura, respectivamente. 

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, 
        delimiter=",", 
        quotechar="'"
    )
    next(reader)  # Para saltarse los headers, la primera linea.

    fieldnames = ['campo2', 'campo3', 'campo4']  #  El nombre de tus headers para escribir.
                                                 #+ en el nuevo archivo.
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow({                      #  Cada uno de los campos los 
            'campo2': cipher.encrypt(row[1]),  #+ encriptas los guardas en un 
            'campo3': cipher.encrypt(row[2]),  #+ diccionario y ese diccionario lo 
            'campo4': cipher.encrypt(row[3])   #+ pasas como parametro para ser
        })                                     #+ escrito en un nuevo csv.
```

Resultando en algo por el estilo (no exactamente).

```
campo2,campo3,campo4
_QO^,^ӍVz▲Cp▼,♫↨;y'
O♫~D,"♫wZS7N▲,Ҳ☺",W断p
6►ː,6rG>y↕>►,♦{<ys
```